# how trust store and key store protect root certificates and private keys?

Tags: certificate, private-key, pki, truststore

root certificate and private keys are very important for establishing a trusted and secure communication channel. My question is these data are protected in systems such as Windows or Linux.

Comment: What do you mean? SSL works between different machines, it's a general protocol.

Comment: my question is not about SSL, but the secure storage of private keys and root certificate on local storage.

Comment: I think I finally understand you: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962112.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Only file password is the security that too can be broken if someone has file system access.
In case of Linux you must keep permissions to minimum possible with readonly to owner of keystore.

Oracle has few solutions like wallet etc but that can be broken as well by tools .